# Hash Generation for an minesweeper game

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, random, hash

I am working on a project for an minesweeper simple game that also generate sha256 hash function to code game results and prove player fairness before we show if he wins or lost.

I need to finish the project as fast possible and I need help.

Also I need for results of hashes to be stored in some kind of database table. It must 3 columns sorted like these: random mines numbers, an random set of strings and numbers, the resulting hash 256SHA function generated from these 2 factors. Also it needs to open the file database and then it must search from all 3 columns but first 256SHA resulting hashes.

Here is what I code so far:

```
 #Statoshi Minswepper game recording.

 import random, random
 import hashlib
 import string
 import os, os.path
 import sqlite3 as lite
 import sys

  #chose some random mines from 25 cells need to redesign function
  boom = random.sample(range(1, 25), 5)
  cellch = raw_input("Chose the cell numbers", )
  print "It explodes BOOM!!!!!", boom
  # A function to generate random characters and numbers
  rchars = string.lowercase + string.digits
  rgen =  "Random Game chars".join(choice(rchars) for x in  range(randint(1,  12))
  #print rgen
  # this is an fair game hash function
  #rchr = boom, rgen
  #print rchr
  #ghash = 
  # I will make now an sqlite3 table to store all data

  con = lite.connect('test.db')

  cars = (
   (1, 'Audi', 52642),
   (2, 'Mercedes', 57127),
   (3, 'Skoda', 9000),
   (4, 'Volvo', 29000),
   (5, 'Bentley', 350000),
   (6, 'Hummer', 41400),
   (7, 'Volkswagen', 21600)
  )


 con = lite.connect('test.db')

 with con:

  cur = con.cursor()    

  cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars")
  cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT)")
  cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(?, ?, ?)", cars)
```

I have worked on a new program version so it is edited. But there are still errors in code and need to redesign all. Any help it will be appreciate. Please give me coding example not only comments.

I hope you will understand the code so far. I have not commented all but I hope that you guys understand what it dose. If you can help me with and class function object oriented I wold appreciate.

Comment: your code should be opening a connexion to a databse somewhere then, you can then set the database to control the access through hash of sha2 like you want and leave that hashing to the DBMS rather than your code

Comment: I try to do that. Quite obvious answer.

Comment: then I don't understand what you need, you just want to write it in python then?

Comment: Please help me with codes.

Comment: Do you know statoshi mines internet game? I want an python version of the game.

Comment: Seems that no one is interested to answer my programing question. I will answer myself after I research more.